# Ex wife moving out the country with my daughters

Tags: international, family-law, france, new-jersey, parental-rights

My ex-wife is planning to move out of the country (to France) next year with my daughters (12 and 10 years old respectively). We have shared custody. I pay alimony (been paying for 7 years, 3 more to go) and child support. We have a good relationship in general.

My questions:

1. What can I do legally to prevent her from moving indefinitely to France? She says it will only be for 2 years but I do not believe it. I believe she's saying so just to not find opposition from my side. I might be OK with her moving for up to 2 years but not more than that.
2. What are the implications in terms of Alimony if she moves out of the country for such a long period of time? What about implications to Child Support?
3. I do not believe she will be living in France with a work permit. I believe she will be working on some kind of informal business. If I am right, and she won't be working "Legally" in France, what can I do here in the US to prevent her from taking my daughters considering the fact that she won't potentially have a better standard of living than the one she has here and the fact that she won't have a work permit to work in France? Can I take her to court and demand that she provides proof of a work permit and job contract?

In general, what are my legal options, if any?

Note: We live in New Jersey

Comment: She may not *need* a work permit.  She will need some legal basis for remaining in France for longer than 90 days, however.  Many avenues for staying in France include an intrinsic right to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Child custody (and alimony) are determined by state courts, so the exact details are state-dependent.

There is no legal basis for a person preventing thrie former spouse from moving (assuming the host country doesn't deny a visa), but the courts *would* be involved in determining whether the child can be taken along: parent A cannot legally just pack up the kids and bolt.

When parents don't agree, then the court must determine what outcome is in the best interest of the child.

- If the children want to move, that counts in favor of them moving ("counts in favor" does not mean "decides the matter").
- If the moving parent doesn't have viable employment prospects abroad, that counts against them moving.
- The amount of time each parent spends with the children also matters, not to mention the laws of your state (here is what the California courts say: ["Move-Away" Situations](http://www.courts.ca.gov/18234.htm)).

Generally speaking, the moving parent has to provide notice, then the non-moving parent has to file a legal action to block the move. Your attorney will discuss all of the relevant considerations with you.

The fact of a parent moving to another country does not *per se* invalidate court-ordered support, but the court can modify an order if circumstances warrant (there's no obvious reason why moving to France would result in modification of such an order).